# How to write this RewriteCond?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to rewrite url from stockpicks.php to stock-picks. When I visit www.website.com/stock-picks will display stockpicks.php page. I use the following rule.

```
RewriteRule ^stock-picks /stockpicks.php [PT]
```

I also want to let search engine know my previous page stockpicks.php permanently move to stock-picks. I use the following rule but 301 redirect seems not working. I guess RewriteCond is not right.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} stockpicks.php$
RewriteRule ^stockpicks.php$ /stock-picks [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The caret, ^, signifies the start of an URL, under the current directory. This directory is whatever directory the .htaccess file is in. You’ll start almost all matches with a caret.

The dollar sign, $, signifies the end of the string to be matched. You should add this in to stop your rules matching the first part of longer URLs.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^stock-picks$ stockpicks.php
```

Answer (score 0):

@Johndave's post takes care of your first requirement.

You'll also need a redirect to for requests asking for stockpicks.php so that they will use /stock-picks/ in future (as that's the new location of this resource that you want to publish).

```
    Redirect permanent /stockpicks.php http://hostname.com/stock-picks/
```

I would use the Redirect directive for this as this is the simplest way to get Apache to send an "HTTP 301 Moved Permanently" response.

Note that this won't get stuck into a loop because the rewrite rule proposed by @Johndave doesn't restart the URL mapping process as specifying the [PT] flag would in your original attempt.

If you do need to use the [PT] flag (in order to get Apache to handle the .php files), then I think you might have conflicting requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The `%{THE_REQUEST}` matches the actual HTTP request, which can look like any of the following:

```
GET /stockpicks/ HTTP/1.1

GET /stockpicks.php?some=stuff HTTP/1.1

HEAD /stockpicks.php

POST /stockpicks.php HTTP/1.0
```

etc.

So you want your `RewriteCond`'s regular expression to look something like this (note the spaces need to be escaped):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /stockpicks.php
```